# Who were the pre-Lekh Likha righteous men?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, historical-figures, mesorah-tradition

BS"D

In Hilkhoth Avodhah Zarah  RaMBaM lists the central figures in the transmission of ethical monotheism, and I was wondering if there were any other figures in our mesora not mentioned. Since the list Rabbeinu compiled is mainly to show the chain of transmission from Adam to Moshe (PBUH), was there anyone else that was also as a important figure in the pre-Avrahamic covenant era, such as an Iyov or Yithro (yes, I know they came after, but just as an example)? Here's the list:

**"The Eternal Rock was not recognized or known by anyone in the world, with the exception of a few individuals. For example: 
Hhanokh, 
Mthushelahh, 
Noahh, 
Shem and Eiver. 
The world continued in this way until the pillar of the world  Avraham our father was born"** [*M"T Hilkhoth Avodah Zarah  1:8 (halakha 2 in the Vilna)*](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1401n.htm#8).

Comment: Just wondering, isn't PBUH an abbreviation generally used by Muslims to refer to Mohammad?

Comment: @Daniel http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him_in_Judaism#Peace_be_upon_him.2Fher

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes I knew what the abbreviation stands for. I had just never seen it used by Jews before. From the linked Wikipedia page: However, unlike in Islamic usage, the English abbreviation "PBUH" is not commonly used for the Jewish honorific.

Comment: @Daniel Yes jews use it too to refer to all of our prophets as a sign of respect. If you read the works of the likes of Sa'adiah Gaon, R. Bahhya ibn Paquda, R. Avraham Ben-Maimon ( mainly in "Guide in the service of Hashem"), RaMBaM etc  you will see if often. Its my communities minhag to give honour to our Navim whenever possible. You probably see it allot but just not the English abbreviation like you said RE: DoubleAA' link.

Comment: @Qoheleth Yes, that is right. עליו השלום I use all the time. I had just never seen the English abbreviation form.